# typoscript conditional typolink-parameter

Tags: if-statement, typo3, typoscript, typolink

TS is confusing :)

I'm trying to create a typolink with a conditional parameter depending on the language.

```
10 = TEXT
  10 {
    typolink {
      parameter = http://myLink.com
      returnLast = url
      if.isTrue.data = GP:L = 1
    }
    wrap (
            <li class="mod-metanav--item">
             <a class="mod-metanav--link" target="_blank" href="|">
              The Link
             </a>
            </li>
    )
  }
```

As you can see, I tried to add an IF-statement to the typolink, asking for a language (at least, that's what I think I did).

The thing is, that, depending on the current language I want a different link (but the rest needs to remain the same).

I could use `[globalVar = GP:L = 1]` but that would create a HUGE overhead, since this typolink is just a fraction of a bigger script-part.

I tried to google for variables or constants that I could add to the parameter, but nothing gave me a useful result...

HELP! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To override the link value depending on the current language you may use the »lang« parameter.

To change the link url depending on the current language you may want to use a CASE object…

```
10 = TEXT
10 {
    value = English
    lang.de = German
    lang.fr = French
    typolink.parameter.cObject = CASE
    typolink.parameter.cObject {
        key.data = GP:L
        1 = TEXT
        1.value = http://example.com/german/bar/
        2 = TEXT
        2.value = http://example.com/french/baz/
        default = TEXT
        default.value = http://example.com/englisch/foo/
    }
    typolink.ATagParams = class="mod-metanav--link"
    typolink.extTarget = _blank
    wrap = <li class="mod-metanav--item">|</li>
}
```

…or you use a constant:

constants:

```
languagedependentlink = http://example.com/englisch/foo/
[globalVar = GP:L = 1]
    languagedependentlink = http://example.com/german/bar/
[global]
[globalVar = GP:L = 2]
    languagedependentlink = http://example.com/french/baz/
[global]
```

setup:

```
10 = TEXT
10 {
    value = English
    lang.de = German
    lang.fr = French
    typolink.parameter = {$languagedependentlink}
    typolink.ATagParams = class="mod-metanav--link"
    typolink.extTarget = _blank
    wrap = <li class="mod-metanav--item">|</li>
}
```

Comment: Another question, if I may: If I want to use a translation.xml, how would I use the value? I tried value = LLL:fileadmin/content/translation.xml:theValue - but this doesn't seem to work... (Uh - I know this must be basic stuff, but I couldn't find a good tutorial or other resource - any hints?)

Comment: You are welcome! For locallang: Just use the data property instead of value. »data = LLL:fileadmin/content/translation.xml:theValue« (See http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/DataTypes/Gettext/Index.html#lll)

Comment: A good start into TypoScript is this tutorial http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptIn45MinutesTutorial/ - A full reference can be found here http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/

Comment: Thanks for both man! Really appreciate the guidance in the TS-jungle :)

Comment: The interesting point about solution 1 is that this never breaks in current versions (which could not be known at that time when this answer was written). That means without conditions the `TypoScript` is compatible to TYPO3 Version 6,7,8,9 and in fall 2019 the coming version 10 too.

Answer (score 0):

And again, I'm answering my own question - may it help somebody else.

```
10 = TEXT
  10 {
    typolink {
      parameter = myLinkInEnglish
      returnLast = url
    }
    wrap (
            <li class="mod-metanav--item">
             <a class="mod-metanav--link" target="_blank" href="|">
              Click here
             </a>
            </li>
    )
    if.value = 1
    if.equals.data = GP:L
  }
```

Again, I'm not satisfied with this since I have to repeat the same block for every language. I'd rather have a variable I could set for the link and the link-text (using translations for the latter).

If someone has a better solution, I'd be happy to know about it...

Comment: Apparently this «kinda» works - I'd recommend pixelbrackets' solution, though

Answer (score 0):

Hm, maybe I'm wrong but it doesn't look like huge overhead:

```
10 = TEXT
  10 {
    typolink {
      parameter = http://worldwide.com
      returnLast = url
    }
    wrap (
            <li class="mod-metanav--item">
             <a class="mod-metanav--link" target="_blank" href="|">
              The Link
             </a>
            </li>
    )
}

[globalVar = GP:L = 1]
10.10.typolink.parameter = http://english.co.uk
[end]

[globalVar = GP:L = 2]
10.10.typolink.parameter = http://german.de
[end]

[globalVar = GP:L = 3]
10.10.typolink.parameter = http://french.fr
[end]
```

Comment: Well, as far as I understand the docs, the [globalVAr...] approach doesn't work inside curly braces {...} - and that's where my typolink is... So pixelbrackets' solution is perfect... I'll add your solution to my book as well, though - might be helpful in other cases :) Thanks!

Comment: Of course, therefore it's outside, - of course if your `10 = TEXT` is nested in some object you need to reflect it and move the condition to the _root_ level of objects ie.: `lib.somemenu.10.10.typolink.parameter = http://german.de`

Comment: Ok, I just learned another thing about typoscript :) - I don't really know which approach would be better. I still like pixelbracket's approach better since it keeps stuff together. Depending on how many variables I have, your approach might end up a little messy... but that's just a noob's view :)

Comment: The best approach is working one :) as _pixelbrackets'_ works for you, that means it's good :)